# How to sort some elements in a list while leaving the rest in place?

Tags: r, list, sorting

I have two slightly different types of lists that I need to sort; however, I only need to sort portions of the list while keeping some elements in place (i.e., their index should stay the same).

First, let's say that I have a list of numbers:

```
x <- c(4, 8, 1, 7, 3, 0, 5, 2, 6, 9)
```

I know that if I only wanted to sort the first 5 elements, then I could do something like this:

```
x[1:5] <- sort(x[1:5])
x

# [1] 1 3 4 7 8 0 5 2 6 9
```

Second, if I wanted to sort a list, but keep NAs in place, then I could do something like this (though I'm sure there's a better way to do this):

```
y <- c(4, 8, 1, NA, NA, 7, 3, 0, 5, 2, NA, 6, NA, 9)

y[which(is.na(y)==FALSE)] <- sort(y[which(is.na(y)==FALSE)])
y

# [1]  0  1  2 NA NA  3  4  5  6  7 NA  8 NA  9
```

**Question**: How do I sort a list with alphanumeric characters by group? So, I want to first sort the list by a pre-defined letter order (i.e., `c(C, A, B)`), then numerically by group, but leave NAs in their original index position?

```
z <- c('B' , 'B1', 'B11', 'B2', 'A', 'C50', 'B21', NA, 'A5', 
       'B22', 'C', NA, 'C1', 'C11', NA, NA, 'C2', NA)
```

**Expected Output**

```
c('C', 'C1', 'C2', 'C11', 'C50', 'A', 'A5', NA, 'B', 'B1', 'B2', NA, 'B11', 'B21', NA, NA, 'B22', NA)

#  [1] "C"   "C1"  "C2"  "C11" "C50" "A"   "A5"  NA    "B"   "B1"  "B2"  NA    "B11" "B21" NA    NA    "B22" NA
```

I know that if I just wanted to sort alphabetically, then I could just use the same code as above. However, these also do not sort correctly numerically.

```
z[which(is.na(z)==FALSE)] <- sort(z[which(is.na(z)==FALSE)])
z

# [1] "A"   "A5"  "B"   "B1"  "B11" "B2"  "B21" NA    "B22" "C"   "C1"  NA    "C11" "C2"  NA    NA    "C50" NA
```

However, I'm not sure how to change the order of the letters to `c(C, A, B)` since these are alphanumeric and to correctly sort numerically. I know that I could use `order` and `match`:

```
f <- sort(z[which(is.na(z)==FALSE)])
z[which(is.na(z)==FALSE)] <- f[order(match(f, c("C","A","B")))]

# [1] "C"   "A"   "B"   "A5"  "B1"  "B11" "B2"  NA    "B21" "B22" "C1"  NA    "C11" "C2"  NA    NA    "C50" NA
```

But that would only change if there is a perfect match (hence only C, A, and B move to the beginning of the list and the groups are then lost), and it would not be prudent to have to give the complete alphanumeric list to `match`. I'm sure there's an easy way to do this (e.g., `grepl`), but am unsure how to implement it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below function, creates an index for non-NA elements ('i1'), extract the letters from the subset of the vector, convert to a `factor` with `levels` specified in the custom order, extract the digits,  `order` the non-NA elements the extracted vectors and assign back, return the updated vector

```
f1 <- function(vec) {
   i1 <- !is.na(vec)
   v1 <- factor(sub("\\d+", "", vec[i1]), levels = c("C", "A", "B"))
   v2 <- sub("\\D+", "", vec[i1])
   v2[!nzchar(v2)] <- 0
   v2 <- as.numeric(v2)
   vec[i1] <- vec[i1][order(v1, v2)]
   vec
   
}
```

-testing

```
f1(z)
[1] "C"   "C1"  "C2"  "C11" "C50" "A"   "A5"  NA    "B"   "B1"  "B2"  NA    "B11" "B21" NA    NA    "B22" NA
```